# How to clone Oracle database from one service name to other service name?

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I have Oracle database and I know SYS password and service name.

I don't have access to database server.

I want to clone database and want to deploy this copy on this database server, but I want have other service name for access to copy.

For example: first base connection string is `localhost:1521/sn1`, and clone have connection string `localhost:1521/sn2copy`.

It is possible?

Comment: Which Oracle version? In 12c (enterprise edition) you can clone a pluggable database through SQL only. But that is not possible in earlier versions

Comment: Version is 11.2.0.4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RMAN has the ability to clone a database.
take a look at the RMAN `DUPLICATE` command.
It's actually documented in the Oracle documentation: [Creating a Duplicate Database on the Local Host](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/backup.111/b28270/rcmdupdb.htm#i1006859) 
.

And also see (from the ORACLE-BASE Blog): [Duplicate a Database Using RMAN in Oracle Database 11g Release 2](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/duplicate-database-using-rman-11gr2)